# Sequence in groups of 10 characters

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, sequence, stringbuffer

I am working on this assignment and I wanted to know how can I display sequence in groups of 10 characters at a time.

Below is the working program screenshot:
[image]

I want to group 10 characters in the output box, for example:

> ```
> 1 CTCTAACGCG CAAGCGCATA TCCTTCTAGG
> 61 ....
> ```

There are about 60 characters in each line excluding spaces and the number, so there must be 6 groups of 10 characters.

Below is the code I made to display this output:

```
public void dispLines() {
    // Get the selected value of characters per line and assign it to noc variable
    String noc = numOfChar.getSelectedItem().toString();
    // Call StringBuffer object and assign sb variable to it
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    // Assign raw dna data to dna variable, where string will be mutated
    String dna = rawDNAInput.getText();
    // Create newdna variable to store the newly created data
    String newdna = "";
    // Loop through the size of raw dna
    for (int i = 0 ; i < dna.length (); ++i)
    {
        // Assign every single character to StringBuffer sb
        sb.append(dna.charAt (i));              
    }       
    // Assign the StringBuffer sb values to the newdna variable
    newdna = sb.toString();
    // Recall StringBuffer object, so new data can be assigned
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    // Assign start varaible of 0
    int start = 0;
    // Assign end varaible to be start + number of characters per line
    int end = start + Integer.parseInt(noc);
    // Keep looping till end value is less than the length of the dna
    while(end < newdna.length())
    {
        // Append values into StringBuffer sb varaible by calling makeNumberedStr method
        sb.append(makeNumberedStr(newdna.substring(start, end), start + 1));
        // Increment start variable by the selected numbers of characters per line
        start += Integer.parseInt(noc);
        // Increment end variable by the selected numbers of characters per line
        end += Integer.parseInt(noc);
    }
    // Append values into StringBuffer sb varaible by calling makeNumberedStr method
    sb.append (makeNumberedStr (newdna.substring (start), start + 1));
    String result = sb.toString();
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

    }
    // Check to make sure uppercase is selected, if it is then make every character uppercase, else make them lowercase
    if(upperCase.isSelected()) {
        DNAOutput.setText(result.toUpperCase());
    } else if(lowerCase.isSelected()) {
        DNAOutput.setText(result.toLowerCase());
    }  
}

/*
 * makeNumberedStr
 * This method only displays required number of characters per line
 * @parameters String x and integer num
 * @returns new StringBuffer value
 */
private String makeNumberedStr (String s, int num)
{
    // makes and returns a string composed from left to right of:
    //   a 6 character field containing right justified [num] followed by 2 spaces
    //   the string s followed by \n
    // Call new StringBuffer object and give it a length of raw dna + 8
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer (s.length ());
    // Create nstr String varaible and give it value of num
    String nstr = String.valueOf (num);
    // Loop through the nstr length and append blank space
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 - nstr.length () ; ++i)
        sb.append (' ');
    // Check if display number is selected, or else do not display number on every line
    if(indexNum.isSelected() == true)
        sb.append (nstr + "  ");
    // Append s value to String Buffer
    sb.append (s);
    // Append new line to StringBuffer
    sb.append ('\n');        
    // Return StringBuffer text
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thank You, much appreciated!

Comment: You know, you have too much comment in the code which makes it unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Run this program, so you have a long string "s", after that i just add code(which automatically count the character's, when it counting reach's to ten, it will automatically put space between the,,), which will help you to add spaces after every ten character, even you don't need to count them...

```
public class PracticeOne {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".{10}", "$0 "));

}
     }
```

the result is

aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaa

hope this will help you

Comment: I understand, but its also counting the amount of spaces there are in the starting of the line and the number.

Comment: can you please put your whole code, than it will be easy to look on it, because your codes have lot of comments, which made it difficult to read...

Answer (score 0):

Without using regular expressions (which is how Akshay GOel's answer was produced) we can add spaces to a StringBuffer with a method like the one below. I think you are using 5 or 6 characters at the start of each line for a number.

```
//Inserts spaces every 10 characters.
//@parm from The index of the buf to begin counting to insert the spaces.
private static void addSpaces(StringBuilder buf, int from) {
   for(int i=from+10; i<buf.length(); i+=11) {
      buf.insert(i,' ');
      // i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: When arranging characters as we are doing in this program, it is best to use a mono-spaced font (e.g. Courrier New, Lucida Console) to help things line up as we expect them to.